# What are the repercussions of not using null termination in strings?

Tags: c, string, char

Take for example the following code:

```
int main(){
    char string[] = { 'h' , 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
    printf(string);
    printf("\n%d", strlen(string));
}
```

The output will be:

```
hello
6
```

So right off the start I can see that the `strlen` value is off by 1, but it doesn't seem like such a hurdle if we account for it.

When does not terminating the string create a problem?

Comment: The behaviour is *undefined*.

Comment: It's undefined behavior. It's already a problem.

Comment: `strlen` needs the null terminator to determine the string length.

Comment: An unterminated `char`-array is not a C-"string". So: "*When does not terminating the string create a problem*"  Always you treat the array as a C-"string". Seemingly working does not mean it "really worked".

Comment: The fact that `strlen` gives you the wrong answer should be enough of a reason to never do something like this.

Comment: `printf(string)` is not correct. You need to specify the format specifier to print string as `%s`. In C strings are null terminated if its not null terminated then its not string,

Comment: As borderline answer to your question, you may try to have a look to functions like `strncpy`, `strncat`, `strncmp` and so on, to handle an array of chars without the null terminator.

Comment: @Giovanni no, that's not correct.

Comment: C is loosely typed and gives you the ability to do lots of invalid stuff. As a programmer, it is your responsibility to make sure you make use of this power properly and avoid shooting yourself in the foot. Your code invokes Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What are the repercussions of not using null termination in strings?

Technically none, because C strings are - [by definition](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1) - terminated by a null character:

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.

So if it's not properly terminated, it's not a string.

If you pass a **non**-string to code that expects a string, you will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala  Given my current wording, you're correct.  I was trying to account for the possibility that there are ways to use a non-string that wouldn't invoke UB.  I'm not prepared to say that's not possible.

Comment: I know you are trying to be helpful, but “Technically none” is more playing with logic than teaching, and it is play that may not be understood by a person trying to comprehend concepts that are not yet familiar. And, technically, it is wrong, as, logically, any conclusion is derivable from a contradiction. If a string is (by definition) null terminated and a string does not (by premise of the question) have a terminating null, this implies that every statement is true, including the fact that the user’s computer will explode.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *it is wrong, as, logically, any conclusion is derivable from a contradiction*  I'm not sure what you mean by contradiction.  The OP didn't meet the definition of what a C string is by failing to properly terminate a "contiguous sequence of characters".  "Technically none" is a succinct way of teaching that definitions matter - that **exact** definitions matter - hopefully in a way that's remembered.

Comment: [If the statements X and ~X are both assumed, then any arbitrary statement can be derived from them.](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/47490/why-do-contradictions-imply-anything/47492). You wrote “Technically none” in response to the question “What are the repercussions of not using null termination in strings?” That question assumes there is no null terminator. You answer that there must be a null terminator. So you had both the assumption in the question that X and the definition that ~X. **Technically**, as you write, the implication of that is everything, not nothing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How on God's good Earth can you say I assumed an impossibility?  "C strings without proper termination" is, by definition, the null set.  It's something that simply does not exist. The concept doesn't contradict anything, and it can't imply any results.  You're reaching, trying to sell dehydrated water.

Comment: The **question** assumes there is no null terminator. Answering a question is implicitly a statement that “If this question is true, then…” If one is not answering what happens **given the conditions of the question**, then what is one answering? Yes, the set of all strings without null terminators is the null set. And that is why it is a problem to assert anything about an element in the set. If S is the null set, and s is an element of s, then “s is red” is never false. Any statement about an element of the null set is never false, because there is never any counterexample to the statement.

Comment: *If S is the null set, and s is an element of s, then “s is red” is never false.* It's also never true, and therefore a completely useless statement. Are you really trying to use "logic" to say you can ascribe characteristics to something that doesn't exist?  What exactly do you believe you're "winning" here?

Comment: The point is you did assert something about an element of the empty set, that there are no consequences. As you write, that is a completely useless statement. The OP’s premise of using a string without a terminating null never occurs, and therefore, to assert that the consequences of doing so are “Technically none” is completely useless.

Answer (score 3):

By definition in C a string must be terminated by a `null termination character`, otherwise it is not a string.

In case the termination character is not used and you try to output the content, you will have an undefined behavior, that just depends on what is contained in the memory after the allocation of the array.

So you could be lucky and have a null termination character because the memory had already the character there, or you could end up printing gibberish on the console and even crash (if you start accessing a forbidden location before finding the `termination character`).

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char string[5];

    memset(string, 'z', 6);

    string[0] = 'h';
    string[1] = 'e';
    string[2] = 'l';
    string[3] = 'l';
    string[4] = 'o';

    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(string));
}
```

In the code I set the character after the memory allocated for the array to the character `z`. If you run this it will mostly crash, since the `printf` starts printing until a null termination character is found (and after the `hello` there is `z` and no termination!).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's consider a simpler program, without any undefined behaviour. What this does is print **5**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[6] = "hello";
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(string));
}
```

And this program has undefined behaviour

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[5] = "hello";
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(string));
}
```

because the null terminator doesn't fit into the `string`, and `strlen` requires the input to be null-terminated. [C11 7.1.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1)

> [...] A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.[...]

and

[C11 7.24.6.3 The strlen function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.3):

> **Description**
>
> 2 The `strlen` function computes the length of the string pointed to by
>   s.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3 The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede
>   the terminating null character.

What's the difference in practice here? When I compile with `-S -O3` to generate assembly, in the first case the number **5** was hardcoded instead of `strlen` being called. In the second case, the optimizer actually *did* realize that it doesn't know what the string length would be and that it needs to call `strlen` for it. However, instead of providing the string in memory, it created it this way:

```
movl    $1819043176, 2(%rsp)
```

I.e. moved a 64-bit constant value `0x6c6c6568` onto the stack... which is little-endian for `hello\0\0\0`. And the code again prints 5. However the compiler *could* have diagnosed this and refused to compile your program altogether, since it is meaningless, having undefined behaviour.

Guess what the program below says upon execution when it is compiled with `gcc -O3 -Werror`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char string[5];
    strcpy(string, "Hello world!!!");
    printf("%zu\n", strlen(string));
}
```

Nothing! Because it doesn't compile, instead spitting out

```
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:494:0,
                 from strcpyexample.c:2:
In function ‘strcpy’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at strcpyexample.c:6:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:90:10: error: ‘__builtin___memcpy_chk’ writing 15 bytes into a region of size 5 overflows the destination [-Werror=stringop-overflow=]
   return __builtin___strcpy_chk (__dest, __src, __bos (__dest));
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: It's even more interesting if you don't have your compiler check for possible problems, and just *run* that sucker. At that point *anything* can happen – up to and including erasing your entire HD or overclocking the monitor refresh so it explodes and you'd be [the Finn Who Got Blown Up](https://books.google.nl/books?id=Lw-00wTgBy8C&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=cryptonomicon+exploding+monitor&source=bl&ots=CzZ_INC7X1&sig=gQlCJIzJ_NbGYxa9y61speAHTJQ&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwieza6JzfndAhXMfFAKHYq1AZkQ6AEwEHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=cryptonomicon%20exploding%20monitor&f=false).

Comment: @usr2564301: Hu?! A tube would never blow up, explode just by "overclocking". Still, the condensers and coils might do this in a awful stinky way, this I can confirm from personal experiences ... ;-)

Comment: @alk: yeah it's sad that part of the story got debunked. At that time I had a freaking *huge* NEC MultiSync, and I'll never forget the ominous klunks it made when switching to hi-rez. (Right after this, the chapter veers off on an unexpected tangent re: antique furniture. But that left no psychic scars on me.)